# Should I zip the Windows installer for download hosted on my website?

Tags: web, download, windows-installer, installation

I host a website where visitor can download Windows application installer.
These Windows application is in *.exe and *.msi format.

As more feature is shipped in into the software, the installer gets bigger.
It used to be 25 Mbs but now it is almost 70 Mbs.

Lately I have been getting some user complaining about failure in downloading the Windows Installer.

Here's the question. Should I zip my installer? Will zipping the installer lower the chance of download failure?

Comment: How much change in size do you see if you zip the installer? I wouldn't expect much, but it may depend on the parameters used to create the cab files that are presumably inside the .msi file.

Comment: 64 Mb after zip, not much difference in size after zipping.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the impact of size on download failures, but the small size reduction seems unlikely to help significantly. At best the nature of compression may force detection of certain kinds of download errors earlier, but so would verifying a signature on the .exe or .msi file.

An approach better suited to handling this may be to use a bootstrapper that can download multiple files (such as external cabs), and retry as necessary. But that won't help the raw .msi file download case. Technically you can run `msiexec /i http://...` to install a .msi and internal or external cabs from a web site, but the failure patterns are not pretty.